# How to check if upload window came from the featured image link?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, links

I need to verify if the media-upload screen came from a click on the "feature image link" on the admin screen. How can i do it?

I've already change the way the uploader works , but I need to check this because there is a special flow for the featured image upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a filter for the html of the 'postimagediv' called 'admin_post_thumbnail_html'.

There may be more elegant ways, but this works:

```
add_filter('admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse61502_change_thumbnail_link');

function wpse61502_change_thumbnail_link($content)
{
    return str_replace('media-upload.php?', 'media-upload.php?is_thumbnail=true&', $content);
}
```

In your plugin / script check the querystring:

```
if ( isset($_GET['is_thumbnail']) )
{
    // do stuff, actions, enqueue, ...
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, ty! 
ps: if ( isset($_GET['is_thumbnail'] )) line needs a ending parethesis,